# How multi dimensional array construct the index in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arrayofarrays

1. int[][][] a = new int[3][3][5];
2. int [][][] b = new int[2][][];
   b[0] = new int[2]; // here why we get error.
   in the above code how java consist each braces.

in java how the above code will allocate memory in concept of array of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here why we get error. in the above code how java consist each braces.

```
int [][][] b = new int[2][][];   //b is an array of (array of (array of int))
b[0] = new int[2];               //b[0] is an (array of (array of int))
```

You are assigning `int[2]` is only an (array of int) to `b[0]`, hence giving you the error.

```
b[0] = new int[2][];             //assign (array of (array of int)) to b[0] --> OK
```

---

In short, `b[0]` is expecting a 2D array, and you are currently assigning it a 1D array and that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The array `int [][][] b = new int[2][][];` is an array of array of array. 
So `b[0]` is an array of array. You are only allocating memory for the first dimension and not the second dimension so you're getting an error. Try `b[0] = new int[2][];`